# Get Pages from MultiPage TIFF

Tags: gdi+, tiff, multipage, libtiff.net

I have a TIFF file that shows 5 pages when opened in Microsoft Document Imaging.  I am trying to extract the 5 pages programmatically and return them in a Lis.

The first page has an 8 bpp indexed format and the last four pages have a 24 bit color format.

I have tried GDI+, TiffBitmapDecoder and BitMiracle's LibTiff.Net but they all return a single page.  The first image returned has one frame so I thought there might be more than one directory in the TIFF file and used LibTiff.Net to get the directory count but it says there is only one directory and also that the image in that directory only contains one frame.

I have tried the code from "How to split multipage Tiff using LibTiff.Net" and it too returns the single image.

What is Microsoft Document Imaging doing?  Is there something else I can try?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: try this link install it and check out your info. www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html it will give you all related info check it once

Comment: Use my TIFFTOOL to see if it's a valid multipage TIFF file (www.bitbanksoftware.com/tinytools.html). Also please post the image so that I can examine it.